# Updating ProgressMonitor from non-plugin library in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, progress-bar

I have a scenario where I have a Java project (`MyLibrary`), which is supposed to be a "pure" Java project with no reference to Eclipse SDK.

I have another project (`MyPlugin`) which is a Plugin project and it uses `MyLibrary`. When calling `MyLibrary`, the plugin project utilises a `ProgressMonitor`.

I am unable to pass the object from MyPlugin to MyLibrary as the latter doesn't have any reference to Eclipse.

How can I update the progress from `MyLibrary`?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't have any public class called `ProgressMonitor`. Is this `IProgressMonitor` you are asking about or something else?

Comment: Yes. It is ``IProgressMonitor`` that I am referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a progress monitor interface to your MyLibrary (`IMyProgressMonitor` for example) that the methods in your library expect to receive.

Your plugin can then implement `IMyProgressMonitor` and just call the corresponding methods on the `IProgressMonitor` you have from Eclipse.